# If $x>0$ , show that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{1}{2^n}<x$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> If $x>0$ , show that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{1}{2^n}<x$

Here what I did,

- Proof by contrapostive
- If for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\space$ $\dfrac{1}{2^n} \geq x$ then $x \leq 0$,
- Since for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,  $\dfrac{1}{2^n} \geq x$
- taking $ n\to \infty$ we have  $x \leq 0$ by the comparison theorem
- therefor If $x>0$ ,  there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{1}{2^n}<x$

Can anyone verify this? if this not correct please correct it?

Comment: Your second line that $x\le 0$ lacks support. Have you considered $\{n\in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mid 2^n>\frac{1}{x}\}$? Can you prove that set has elements, and all of its elements are positive integers? (Use the fact that the set of integers has no greatest element, so the set must be nonempty). Then, use well-ordering to show you can actually find an element of the set. Take the reciprocal and you are done.

Comment: @SlipEternal what about my proof actually I don't see any  mistake there that is why I ask it. thank you for your help it is very interesting

Comment: @SlipEternal Can you explain?

Comment: Your proof is correct but you use the result $\frac{1}{2^n} \to 0$ which is consequence of what you want to proof because :
$$\dfrac{1}{2^n} \to 0 \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N, \frac{1}{2^n} \leq \varepsilon$$
I think you have to look for an elementary proof.

Comment: "Taking $n \to \infty$" ... OK ... **but** in most real analysis courses, you would be doing this sort of thing before doing $\lim 1/2^n = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n = \left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{x} \right\rfloor + 1$ we have :
$$\dfrac{1}{x} < n = \underbrace{1 + \ldots + 1}_{n \text{ times}} \leq 1 + 2 + \cdots + 2^{n - 1} = 2^n$$
So :
$$\dfrac{1}{2^n} < x$$

Answer (score 2):

Binomial expansion:

$2^n=(1+1)^n=$

$1+n+n(n-1)/2!+.....> n. $

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.

$n>1/x.$

The result follows.

Comment: +1 for referring to Archimedean property.

Comment: Hermis14. Thanks:))

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct (assuming you can use the comparison theorem) but the presentation could be better.

For instance you write,

- Proof by contrapositive
- If for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{2^{n}}\geq x$ then $x\leq0$,

the second point reads like a fact which you already know (which is not the case).

If you use words, you can express the above points without ambiguity, for example as follows:

> We want to do a proof by contrapositive. Therefore we assume that
> for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{2^{n}}\geq x$ and
> show that $x\leq 0$.

The rest of your proof should also be written in a single text with words that connect previous sentences and explain your reasoning. Don't use lists unnecessarily, they can ruin the flow of reading and often require further explanations to avoid ambiguity.

With all that in mind your proof can be written

> We want to do a proof by contrapositive. Therefore we assume that
> for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{2^{n}}\geq x$ and
> show that $x\leq 0$. Since $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ approches zero as $n\to \infty$, our assumption that $\frac{1}{2^{n}}\geq x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ implies by the comparison theorem that $x\leq 0$, which is what we wanted to prove.